# Windows 7 laptop's volume with headphones way too loud

Tags: windows-7, audio, sound-card

I have two headphones, neither has any amps or volume control, and both have the same problem with this computer.  I normally have the volume on 10%, and that is optimal.  I'm still very afraid that someday it will be at 100% and i'll accidentally have my headphones on.

I tested how loud it is at maximum volume -- it's earsplittingly loud!  In fact, it's so loud that if I lay the headphones down on the table, I can listen to a song perfectly clearly from meters away.

Is there any way to make the volume control more safe for the ears?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 Audio Too Loud](http://superuser.com/questions/405178/windows-7-audio-too-loud)

Comment: @Zoredache if you feel that way, please vote to close.

Comment: @soandos, I already have, a couple months ago when I made the comment.  I suspect my [close vote expired](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120896/why-do-close-votes-expire).

Comment: @Zoredache, my apologies, didn't realize the question was that old.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the soundcard, but laptop adapters usually come with an output limiting function to protect the little speaker(s) they have. It should also limit the output to the earphone jack as well:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: My **Speakers Properties** dialog box does not have a **Custom** tab. On my **Levels** tab, my Speakers volume are set to "0", and they are still so loud I can't hear what my coworkers are saying when they ask me something.

Answer (score 2):

Check the control panel that comes with your third party audio driver.  Open the **Start** menu and type "audio".  Something may come up under Programs or Control Panel.

[image: IDT Audio Control Panel]

Depending on your software, you may be able to set independent volume levels for the speakers and the headphones.

Comment: Dell had a setting called "Maxx volume" that was making the headphones much too loud.  When turned off the sound was a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like [http://www.amazon.com/Koss-155954-VC20-Volume-Control/dp/B00001P4XH](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00001P4XH) or something similar is what your looking for

Answer (score 1):

If your soundcard doesn't come with software to lower the general volume, try this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/

I installed it and set the gain to -50 dB.

Before I did that, I could only use the volume to between 0 and 2 on Windows' volume dial.

Now I can use the whole range from 0–100, which makes it a lot easier to set the volume correctly.